# SQL Port 1433 needed in SQL Server2008 IP Field for remote connection

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2, sql-server-2008

I just installed SQL Server 2008 on my server.  I do it often enough to forget what to do so I read through a couple of MS installation instructions.  I installed with no issues.  I tried to remote into the server from another computer using SQL Server Management Studio.  I spent several unsuccessful hours trying to log into the server.  The error I kept getting was error 26, "Server not found".  I tried many things including making sure that my server firewall and cloud service firewall had ports 1433 & 1434 were open.  I read an post that had the SQL port number after the server URL.  I tried the following server name with the IP port and it worked.

myservername.net, 1433\WIN-RQKC744KMH9

I guess this is ok but is there a way I can eliminate the need to include the 1433.  My TCP/IP properties are all correct and point to 1433 including IPALL.  By the way, I am using Amazon EC2 as my server platform.  I can't use VPN because of the eventual application environment planned for this server.  Although the problem is just an irritation, any help is much welcome.

Regards,
Steve Mansfield

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your TCP/IP settings are correct?  They're confusing.  Namely, you have to make TCP Dynamic ports blank in order to turn it off dynamic ports.  (The default value is 0.  I invariably set it to 1 before remembering that I have to delete the value instead.)